# How to load images in a GridView layout?

Tags: java, android, button

I was following the `GridView` tutorial http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/grid_view but this tutorial only uploads the images from the `Drawables` folder but how can I get the user to specify a location of a folder of images on the Android device (via clicking a button) and then those images to appear in the `GridView`.

I am a beginner so please provide some explanation with your code so that it will help me understand easily.

Comment: Here is the duplicate question..


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571854/loading-images-from-url-instead-if-locally/18572055#18572055

Answer (score 1):

This one is best choice for you https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

**Features**

1. Multithread image loading
2. Possibility of wide tuning ImageLoader's configuration (thread executors, downlaoder, decoder, memory and disc cache, display image options, and others)
3. Possibility of image caching in memory and/or on device's file sysytem (or SD card)
4. Possibility to "listen" loading process
5. Possibility to customize every display image call with separated options
6. Widget support

Comment: Hi, is there a simpler version because that looks really complex for my application.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used gridlayout but if you want to load the image 
you can use the WebView (just read about the webview of android).

you can use 
WebView webview=new WebView();
webView..loadDataWithBaseURL("here is your path of the image");

Try this one.

Comment: Hi, I guess that can work but what do I need to change in the code in the tutorial?

Comment: If you try using @Amit's suggestion you'll get only one single image at a time

Comment: @MAD4RA hi thanks for pointing it out, is there a simpler and quicker way?

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try searching "**Dynamically add images to a gridview**" 
Here's [Clue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790268/dynamically-adding-images-to-gridview)